# Have Goroutine and C# async/await same effect

Tags: c#, go, async-await, goroutine

Using async/await aproach if process continue on different cpu from our application server is can be very useful.

For example a database query runs on database server, no need to block application thread while query is running. You can check it from [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Advanced/Introduction-To-Async-Await-And-Tasks--C-Advanced-5-of-8).

Lets look at that c# code block

```
 public async Task SaveAsync(User user)
    {
        using (DataContext ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            ctx.User.Add(user);
            // database does its job while we are waiting
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

So has goroutine code below same effect ?

```
func (u *User) Create(userModel *model.User) error {
var err error
var wg sync.WaitGroup
//or channel can be used for sync 
wg.Add(1)  //wg := make(chan int)


go func() {
    defer wg.Done(). //wg <- 1
    _, err = u.Transaction.User.
        Create().
        SetAge(userModel.Age).
        SetName(userModel.Name).
        SetIsDeleted(false).
        Save(u.Ctx)
   
}()

wg.Wait() //    <-wg
if err !=nil{
    return err
}
return nil}
```

Comment: They are not really the same, In fact async and await will not block or use any threads and IO work queued up on the hardware / operating system with a callback that runs a continuation on the calling thread depending on how the statrmachine is configured amung other things

Comment: So goroutine does not use and not block threads aslo, am I wrong ?

Comment: Consider reading [this classic essay](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) which deals with async/await and Go's goroutine scheduler with integrated pollable I/O.

Comment: You Go code makes no sensible use of a goroutine: Drop the go routine and WaitGroup stuff and the code does and behaves exactly the same. Maybe the best thing is to just understand what goroutines are and how they map to threads (it doesn't matter much, it just works for unpatological cases) instead of trying to understand goroutines by making vague associations to async/await which is a totally different programming model.

Comment: To learn how Go's scheduler deals with blocking I/O, start [there](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) then continue [there](https://rakyll.org/scheduler/).

Comment: Just to stress this once more: the programming model of Go with goroutines allows you to write simple concurrent code _without_ having to worry how goroutines are scheduled, what blocks or doesn't block etc.

Comment: "Goroutines" execute concurrently. `async`/`await` do **NOT** execute concurrently.

Comment: Even though `async`/`await` and `goroutines` serve the same purpose of asynchrony, both are day and night apart in terms of their implementations. Goroutines start usually on their own lightweight threads and are synchronized through channels. On the other hand, async/await calls are modeled as state machines underneath the hood because a simple stack model is not the right fit to handle the flow of control of asyn calls of `C#`. Take a look at this to understand the asynchrony in `go` - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wAaf1rYoM4S4gtnPh0zOlGzWtrZFQ5suE8qr2sD8uWQ/pub

Comment: So using goroutine if no need concurrency, does not increase the cpu efficency opposite to c# async/await. Thank you all.
And one more question, I really do not understand why my questions is minus rated, is this question that foolish or unnecesarry ?

Comment: @MSK - `async`/`await` does not increase CPU efficiency. It is simply serialized asychrony. In fact it makes the CPU do more work.

Comment: I mean excatly same by using efficency; "CPU do more work" . Is it wrong usage of term @Enigmativity ? If so, could you please tell me how should update my question ?

Comment: @MSK - I think you're being down-voted because your question contains a bunch of false assumptions. You've even provided a link to another question and answer on this site and completely misquoted what it says. You seem to have started with a bad understanding and you've summarised in the comments with a further bad understanding. The purpose of down-votes is to indicate that this question is flawed and show not be used as a good source of information for future readers.

Comment: @MSK - "CPU do more work" is efficiency? No, efficiency is getting the same amount of work done in a shorter time. `async`/`await` can cause a computation to go slower, because of the state-machine and that the program can execute unrelated work. That's the opposite of efficiency.

Comment: I updated my question, thank you.
And if efficiency is getting the same amount of work done in a shorter time, yes it is excatly true that Async/await is increasing CPU efficiency. For example when you use async/await in db operations (db hosted another server), a web api can handle much more request without using async/await.

Comment: @MSK - That's not CPU efficiency. That's network or I/O efficiency. With both technologies you're looking at you are starting with a fixed amount of CPU work and you're adding to it. It's not making the CPU more efficient, it's making it worse.

Comment: I see @Enigmativity, you mean async/await couses using other app server resources more efficient way. 
Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220883/discussion-between-msk-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goroutines and async/await are different approaches to asynchronous programming. Under the hood you have P processes M CPU cores and G coroutines. Your language runtime operates them - checks when one should be stopped (unscheduled from real processes and thus CPU cores) and others should be scheduled to cores.

What approach is better? It depends on developer. As for me async/await has more syntax sugar, goroutines is more explicit in terms of programming. So first can be more concise, second - easier understandable in complex cases like `select {..}` and so on.